# expand a div from both side (up and down)

Tags: jquery

When we use slideDown or Up it slides the element up or down from bottom. is there a way to slide that from both side without centering the element continuously ?

**edit:**
element is absolute and should start sliding from center of page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `slideDown`, animate the element's height and margin-top.

**[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/7nZrA/)**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, position the div using `position:absolute` and `bottom:..px` for example

Comment: the problem is that the `div` does not start to sliding from center

Comment: @OmidAmraei oh sorry i thought you wanted it to animate only from the bottom